# Can't find installed manifest.json for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find my Chrome extension's App ID so that I can get User Authentication. I have installed my extension and when I go to chrome://extensions/ I can see the ID:

[image]

However, in the Developer's Dashboard, the url is showing a different App ID:
[image]

I know that I somehow have to sync them so that they are the same. The Google tutorial for getting user authentication says that I should go to the user data directory to find my installed extension and copy the key from the manifest there to the manifest in my source directory. However, I can't find my extension in the user data directory under google-chrome/Default/Extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your manifest will always be at: [chrome-extension://myId/manifest.json](http://chrome-extension://myId/manifest.json)

When you create an extension on the store, Google will pick a random id and assign it to your extension.

When you install an extension(from your computer to your computer) to chrome, your computer will assign it an id.

Only once in a billion lifetimes will those two be the same.

always use the id you see in the [chrome://extensions](http://chrome://extensions) page to find the manifest.

Comment: Had no idea I could access the manifest through a link in my browser. Thanks!

Comment: no problem.  you can access the whole extension directory though the url.  chrome-extension://myId/folder_inside_extension/file.js or png or whatever!

Comment: option pages, popups(such as those in the top right corner), and all else are actually simply windows to those urls.

Comment: Ah, I see. So does that mean that this directory is not actually stored locally at all? (Apart from the source directory)

Comment: yes, it is stored locally. for example, you can access any file on your computer using a file:// url.  chrome-extension:// is simply a shortcut that refers to the location where chrome stores the extension files (and allows file-to-file access within the directory).